fastapi : "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
I recently updated fast api from v0.89.1 to v0.110.0 and I am getting the following error.
"GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
There is no other error to help me debug the issue.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:portNumber (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [xxxxx] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [xxxxx]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found

Everything was working fine before the upgrade.

We can't say much without seeing your code.  Do you have a handler for /docs?

@TimRoberts you don't need a handler for /docs in fastapi. Unless you are passing in docs_url=None when starting up the service, then it comes for free.

Have you tried explicitly setting docs_url and have you tried the redoc endpoint? What do your logs say?

@scrappedcola nothing in the logs so it is difficult to debug the issue.

Your error message is for / while your text says /docs.

Does this or this answer your question?

removing this line fixed the issue root_path="/",

removing root_path="/" fixed the issue
